# Large number of categories for categorical features in the dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, data-science, multilabel-classification

I have a dataset which have 13 features in total, out of which 5 features are Categorical features. Now these features have 1700, 25, 65, 275 and 3 different categories available respectively. I will convert these categorical features to numeric data using available encoding techniques before applying ML algorithms.

Problem that I am working on is a multiclass classification.

My question is do I need a large amount of data (in hundreds of thousands) to make my model learn different combinations of each category available to me effectively?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info (and notice that the idea is *not* to remove the tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,you don't need an especially large amount of data.

This is a common issue concerning high-cardinality categorical features, which you will find a lot of information on if you look it up.

One approach is known as target encoding, where the feature is encoded by taking into consideration the corresponding values of the target (i.e. labels).

See [TargetEncoder](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/targetencoder.html) from `scikit-learn` for example.

Comment: Thankyou for letting me know this. I will implement it in my code!

Answer (score 0):

While working with multiclass classification problems, it is best to have same number of samples for each target class. If not then it becomes an imbalanced dataset.

To answer your question, features count wouldn't play that crucial role as that of target, so you need not have large amount of data.

Comment: I think I am unable to express my question properly. What I mean is as I have large number of categories for each categorical feature (1700+ for one catgeory), so to make my model learn different combinations across different categorical features do I need large number of data?